# Link on specified cords

Tags: html, image, coordinates, href

Is it possible to make a link on a specified cords of the image in HTML?

I got an image and I want the link to be available only on the specified position of it. I dont really know if its possible, but if so, please give me some tips.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cords? Electric cords, guitar chords, corduroys? What do you mean?

Comment: @JaredFarrish I have specified which cords in my question.

Comment: What link are you talking about? The image's link?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal No, my own link - I would like to make the link click able on certain position of the image....

Comment: That's called an *image map*. Good keyword to base further research on.